# A diamond's goodbye

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

In a few hours our 2019 moderator election will conclude a new moderator to join the team, and I will step aside.

It's been 4.5 years since I was [elected](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/election/1) and a lot has happened since then. We've continued to grow as a community, we've evolved and seen contributors join (and leave) and I feel grateful, honoured and privileged that I've able to been part of this journey as a moderator. During these same 4 years my focus and occupations have slowly shifted too. So as we've seen Adrian's moderation flourish my own activity decreased. And this community deserves so much more than a fragment of a mod's attention, yet that's  what my contributions have evolved to.

I am happy to see moderator nominees that have shown and proven an incredible commitment and desire to contribute, and are ready to take on a role as moderator. Do [cast your vote](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/election/3) if you have not done so.

While I am sure this is not the end of my activity here (I am sure habits and google search will make me come here often enough), I did want to write a little something down :-).

Thank you for having me as a mod.

Samuel

Comment: Thanks and all the best to you for the next chapter :)

Comment: Terrific work and the community really appreciated your endeavors

Comment: Your contributions have been most welcome. Can't wait to see what you'll do next!

Comment: I'm late to chime in here, but your efforts and contributions here as a moderator have greatly contributed to the success and growth of this forum. You've represented us well and can be proud of the time you've invested. My thanks to you for all you've done my friend.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thank you so much for the work you have put in here. You have been a steadfast presence since Day One. Hopefully this new chapter in SFSE brings great things, and all the best in your new chapter as well. If I run in to you at another Dreamforce you'll have to let me buy you a pint. :)